# How to fix None returned as torch version?

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, version

I'm using Python 3.9.7 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on Windows 11.
I tried both torch 1.10.2 and torch 1.11.0. In both cases the version.parse function returns None. `version.parse(importlib_metadata.version("torch"))`.
So, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-c243c65504c9>", line 1, in <module>
    version.parse(importlib_metadata.version("torch"))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bertopic._bertopic import BERTopic
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\_bertopic.py", line 31, in <module>
    from bertopic.backend._utils import select_backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\backend\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._word_doc import WordDocEmbedder
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\backend\_word_doc.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bertopic.backend._utils import select_backend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\backend\_utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._sentencetransformers import SentenceTransformerBackend
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\bertopic\backend\_sentencetransformers.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ParallelSentencesDataset import ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\datasets\ParallelSentencesDataset.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 11, in <module>
    import transformers
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\transformers\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import dependency_versions_check
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\transformers\dependency_versions_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .generic import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\generic.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .import_utils import is_flax_available, is_tf_available, is_torch_available, is_torch_fx_proxy
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\transformers\utils\import_utils.py", line 350, in <module>
    torch_version = version.parse(importlib_metadata.version("torch"))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 49, in parse
    return Version(version)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\SentiAnalysis\lib\site-packages\packaging\version.py", line 264, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this error with torch 1.10 or 1.11 with python 3.9. Make sure you have installed the latest package of importlib_metadata

Comment: @darthbaba Thank you for your reply. I installed importlib_metadata  3.10.1, but the error is not gone.

Comment: I uninstalled `torchaudio` , and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found some torch-XYZ0-info folder in my environment site_packages folder that caused the same behavior. cleaning it up solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).